# Rails 3 respond_with, route constraints and resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, routes, mongoid

I'm building a versioned API, so I have the following nested controllers:

- `ApiController < ApplicationController`
- `Api::V1Controller < ApiController`
- `Api::V1::EventsController < Api::V1Controller`

The API is accessed via a subdomain. I have the following routes:

```
  constraints(:subdomain => "api") do
    scope :module => 'api' do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :events
      end
    end
  end
```

This produces the type of URL I want (/v1/events).

The problem I'm facing is when using `responds_with` in `Api::V1::EventsController`. Just doing something as simple as the below fails with the error `too few arguments`:

```
def index
    @events = Event.all
    respond_with(@events)
end
```

I know `respond_with` is meant to be used with resources, but I'm not sure how the events resource should be accessed from the constrained, scoped, and namespaced route. I can output other things (such as current_user), just not an array of events. Help?

**Update:**

Here's what works:

```
# a single resource
def index
    @event = Event.all.first
    respond_with @event
end

# an array of a completely different resource
def index
    @user = User.all
    respond_with @user
end
```

So maybe it has something to do with the Event model, specifically collections vs. arrays. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: same thing for me, and i am using mongoid too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like:

```
respond_with [:v1, @events]
```

Comment: Can you add or link to your full log somewhere?

Comment: Did you try to add the third argument: respond_with [:api, :v1, @events] ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding the third argument, as well as every variation I could think of. I forgot to mention that I'm using Mongoid and not ActiveRecord, if that makes a difference.